# Script tag not printing any message

Tags: javascript, html

In the given code , I am trying to print the message but after taking input its not printing any message.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>CSS</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form onsubmit="return Ak()">
                <input type="text" name="abinash" placeholder="abinash"  required id="q"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                <div id="w"></div>
            </form>
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function Ak()
                {
                    var y=document.getElementById("q").value;
                    document.getElementById("w").innerHTML="You have typed this password"+y;
                    
                 
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: For me it works normally (at least I think it is normal :). You only did not wrote `event.preventDefault();` to onsubmit="" attribute of form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing the submit button will refresh the page.
`event.preventDefault();` use this keyword.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function Ak()
        {
            var y=document.getElementById("q").value;
            document.getElementById("w").innerHTML="You have typed this password"+y;
            event.preventDefault();

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It was working, but after submitting form, all of content disappeared. You need to add `event.preventDefault();` to onsubmit attribute of form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>CSS</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return Ak()">
                <input type="text" name="abinash" placeholder="abinash"  required id="q"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                <div id="w"></div>
            </form>
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function Ak()
                {
                    var y=document.getElementById("q").value;
                    document.getElementById("w").innerHTML="You have typed this password"+y;
                    
                 
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

## event.preventDefault()

It **is** working, it's just that when you click that submit button the page reloads. I tried it out, and you can fix it by adding e.preventDefault(); to your function, and put (e) as the arg in the function, like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>CSS</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return Ak()">
                <input type="text" name="abinash" placeholder="abinash"  required id="q"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                <div id="w"></div>
            </form>
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function Ak()
                {
                    var y=document.getElementById("q").value;
                    document.getElementById("w").innerHTML="You have typed this password: "+y;
                    
                 
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but the message will disappear because the form is successfully submitted. If you want it to stay on the screen, just return `false` from the `Ak()` function:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onsubmit="return Ak()">
            <input type="text" name="abinash" placeholder="abinash"  required id="q"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            <div id="w"></div>
        </form>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Ak()
            {
                var y=document.getElementById("q").value;
                document.getElementById("w").innerHTML="You have typed this password"+y;
                
                return false;
             
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```